# c++ template ambiguous error

Tags: c++, templates

Here's my code trying  to simply add 2 numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template<class first, class second>
first plus(first x, second y) {

    return x + y;
}
int main() {

    int a = 123;
    int b = 21;

    plus(a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

The plus() gives me an error stating that it's "ambiguous". This is basically copied code I've seen in tutorials(where it has worked!) on templates so I'm really confused now.

Comment: Try to remove `using namespace std;` or call it like this: `::plus(a, b);` or wrap it inside a namespace.

Comment: std::plus exists.

Comment: I suspect that it has to do with `using namespace std` and the fact that there is a [`std::plus`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus)

Comment: Worked, thanks. remove using namespace std;

Comment: I hope you learned that `using namespace std;` is a bad practice.

Comment: also the fact std::plus exist so changing the function name also works..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: @SS2, or, namespaces are a honking good idea, let's do more of those. IE, don't drag everything from another namespace into the current one.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `using namespace std`, you are colliding with `std::plus`

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus

Answer (score -2):

I've solved the issue either removing std namespace or changing the function name is all it takes!